# issue regarding PHP, Jquery and Ajax.

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an issue at the moment regarding PHP, Jquery and Ajax.

I have a a div at the bottom of my page that has data in it from a database, now for every iteration of the data a new div is formed, the div has an id of 'pagestatus' and has an auto increment next to it so the id changes for each div like so: 'pagestatus0', 'pagestatus1' etc.

Now I'm not completely new to Jquery as I have used it to make pages more interactive and I've used Ajax to update a MySQL database.

I'm having trouble with the code though, I would like it go something like this:

- Button is clicked in div
- Button fades in (or div, which ever is easier)
- A hidden div with a loading gif appears underneath
- Ajax calls to the php file to make changes to the database
- jquery then fades the loading gif back out and fades the button back in

I have wrote some code for it but I think I am going wrong somewhere, could someone see what I am doing wrong and let me know how to fix it.

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0;i<$('#changestatusoff').val();i++){
        (function(x){
            $('#changestatusoff'+x).click(function(){
                $('#changestatusoff'+x).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                    $('#loadingstatus').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '.php',
                            data: {'changestatusoff': changestatusoff}, 
                            success: function(data) {
                                return data;
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                alert('Error occured');
                            }
                            $('#loadingstatus').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                                $('#changestatusoff'+x).fadeIn('slow',function();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });         
    }
})(i);
});
```

And here is the button in the div:

```
<input type='button' value='Offline' id='changestatusoff".$count."' style='background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 118, 188); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; margin:5px;'/>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you paste an example of the HTML? ;-)

Comment: Where are you setting the `changestatusoff` variable? And instead of looping over all the IDs, why don't you use a class?

Comment: There is a syntax error after "alert('Error occured');}
I think there should be a ");" to end ajax function call.

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned, we have no idea what you are submitting ;-)

Use a class, which means it dosent have to make a new bind for each item, it can do it all at once.

You could do something like:

```
$(function() {
    //set loading
    var $loading = $('#loadingstatus');

    //on changeStatus click
    $('.changeStatus').click( function(e) {
        //since we dont have a form, disable default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
        //set $this as the item clicked
        var $this = $(this);
        //fadeIn loading, fadeout the item
        $this.fadeOut();
        $loading.fadeIn();
        //make ajax request
        $.ajax
            ({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'yourPhpFile.php',
            data: {'changestatusoff': $(this).val()}, 
            success: function(data) {
                //Do something with data?
                $loading.fadeOut();
                $this.fadeIn();
            },
            error: function() {
                //Do nothing, and tell an error happened
                alert('An error occured');
                $loading.fadeOut();
                $this.fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check `data: {'changestatusoff': changestatusoff}` and try changing it to `data: {changestatusoff: 'changestatusoff'}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change loading gif back, then you should put the last two lines:

```
$('#loadingstatus').fadeOut('slow',function(){
$('#changestatusoff'+x).fadeIn('slow',function();
```

in completed callback, not after ajax call.

```
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: '.php',
data: {'changestatusoff': changestatusoff}, 
success: function(data) {
    return data;
},
error: function() {
    alert('Error occured');
},
completed: function() {
    $('#loadingstatus').fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $.('#changestatusoff'+x).fadeIn('slow',function();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(function(){
   $('#Your_Event_Source').click(function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(600);
      $('#loadingstatus').fadeIn(600);
      $.post('you_file.php',{changestatusoff: 'yourValue'},function(data){
         if(data.success == 'yes'){
             alert(data.message);
             $('#Your_Event_Source').fadeIn(600);
             $('#loadingstatus').fadeOut(600);
         }else{
             alert('failed'+ data.message);
             $('#Your_Event_Source').fadeIn(600);
             $('#loadingstatus').fadeOut(600);
         }
      },'json');
   });
});
```

I recommend to use 'success' in php:

```
$data = array('success'=>'yes','message' => 'your meaasage',...);
echo json_encode($data);
```